# some questions on Garbage Collection internals?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I am trying to understand how Garbage collection process works. Came across good [link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html) .
Most of the articles says that during minor GC collection object is moved from eden to survivor space and during major GC collection
object is moved from survivor to tenured space otherwise all unreachable objects memory is reclaimed. I have three questions(need to ask
in single go as they are related) based on above statements :-

1)`Minor vs Major GC collection ? What is the difference between two that one is called major and other is called minor collection?`
As per my understanding during minor collection happens in parallel to application run  while major collection makes application to
pause during that period.

2) `What actually happens when object is moved from eden to survivor space ? Does the memory location of object is changed internally?`

3) `Why not just one space exist instead of three i.e eden, survivor and tenured space exist ?` I know there is must be a reason behind it but i am missing it.
My point is when GC runs , collect unreachable object and leaves the reachable ones in that space only. Just one space seems to be sufficient. So what advantage three different
spaces are proving over one?

Comment: First you need to understand that asking how "garbage collection" works is different from asking how the specific version of GC works in Oracle's JVMs.  There are many potential implementation strategies, and Oracle's is only one of those.

Comment: Cleaning up a small region with mostly dead objects is pretty quick.  Sifting through a lot of older objects which are unlikely to be cleaned up slows down the collections time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Minor GC occurs on new generation, major GC occurs on old generation. Whether it is parallel to the application or not depends on the kind of GC, only CMS and G1 can work concurrently

2) Yes, moving object during GC changes its physical location so all pointers to this object will be updated

3) This is to avoid often and long application freezing during GC. If it was one big heap then application would often freeze for long periods of time. JVM creates objects in small young generation, GCs in it occur frequently but quickly. Most objects created by JVM die quickly and they never get to old generation, so major GC happens rarily or it may never happen at all.

Comment: Question regarding point 2. Say i print reference of object. Now Minor GC runs, there is a probability that reference changes once i print the reference again if the object is live. Right ? Though it wont happen on Major GC as objects are not moved to another space during that period.

Comment: 1) you cannot access reference to the object 2) major GC may move object inside old generation while compacting it (removing gaps)

Comment: 1) We can get memory location of object with System.identityHashCode(). Is n't it ?

Comment: hashcode may be based on internal address but in any case once created it never changes

Comment: You mean to say that even if memory address changes after GC run, System.identityHashCode() will continue to return memory location for initially created object ?

Comment: Hashcode is not necessarily based on address, it's just an int, JVM is free how to create it, read Object.hashCode docs to the end. One thing is sure once created it never changes. Hashcode once created (and it may be lazy, on demand) is stored in objects header, so it moved in memory together with the object.

Comment: At least for HotSpot it seems major GC occurs for all objects across all generations, but besides that, nice answer!

Comment: @MSach In Hotspot, the identityHashCode() is stored in the header.  You can read this and even changes it by access the memory directly.  You can check this yourself by creating an object, printing it and performing a System.gc() and creating another object etc.  The memory location of the start of the eden space doesn't change but you get a different hashCode() each time.

Comment: @MSach You can see the address by using Unsafe. Assuming you have have compressed oops you can store the address in an Object[] and read it as an `int`, This gives you an address based index. (for less than 2 GB heap it can be the actual address)

Answer (score 1):

Source for my answers is [this Oracle article on GC basics](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html), so these answers would apply for HotSpot. No clue as to other VMs, although I would guess that the general idea might remain the same if the same implementation techniques were used in other VMs.

> Minor vs Major GC collection? What is the difference between two that one is called major and other is called minor collection?

Minor GC is GC of the young generation, where new objects are allocated. Major GC is GC of all live objects, including the permanent generation (which is a bit interesting to me, but that's what the article says). Also, it appears that *both* major and minor GC are stop-the-world events.

> What actually happens when object is moved from eden to survivor space? Does the memory location of object is changed internally?

I can't seem to find a reference at the moment, but I would assume so. Allowing for memory location to be changed lets compaction be performed, which improves memory allocation performance and ease. Allowing each space to be compacted separately makes sense, so I would guess that moving an object from one part of the heap to another would involve physically moving the object from one memory location to another.

> Why not just one space exist instead of three (i.e eden, survivor and tenured space) exist?

Short answer: efficiency. If you have only one space, you'd have to check all objects when you GC, which becomes inefficient if you have lots of long-lived objects (and you're almost guaranteed to have a decent number in a long-running application), as those long-lived objects are likely to still be reachable from one GC to the next. Splitting the heap allows for GC to be optimized, as most of the GC efforts can be concentrated where object life can be assumed to be short (i.e. young generation), with longer-living objects being GC'd less frequently.