# How to confirm the reason for the full gc is to expand metaspace?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I use `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` to use `cms gc`,and `-XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps` to print the detail gc log.

Here is the full gc log.

```
2017-03-20T16:23:07.321-0200: 64.425: [GC (CMS Initial Mark) [1 CMS-initial-mark: 10812086K(11901376K)] 10887844K(12514816K), 0.0001997 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs]
2017-03-20T16:23:07.321-0200: 64.425: [CMS-concurrent-mark-start]
2017-03-20T16:23:07.357-0200: 64.460: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 0.035/0.035 secs] [Times: user=0.07 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
2017-03-20T16:23:07.357-0200: 64.460: [CMS-concurrent-preclean-start]
2017-03-20T16:23:07.373-0200: 64.476: [CMS-concurrent-preclean: 0.016/0.016 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.00, real=0.02 secs]
2017-03-20T16:23:07.373-0200: 64.476: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean-start]
2017-03-20T16:23:08.446-0200: 65.550: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.167/1.074 secs] [Times: user=0.20 sys=0.00, real=1.07 secs]
2017-03-20T16:23:08.447-0200: 65.550: [GC (CMS Final Remark) [YG occupancy: 387920 K (613440 K)]65.550: [Rescan (parallel) , 0.0085125 secs]65.559: [weak refs processing, 0.0000243 secs]65.559: [class unloading, 0.0013120 secs]65.560: [scrub symbol table, 0.0008345 secs]65.561: [scrub string table, 0.0001759 secs][1 CMS-remark: 10812086K(11901376K)] 11200006K(12514816K), 0.0110730 secs] [Times: user=0.06 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
2017-03-20T16:23:08.458-0200: 65.561: [CMS-concurrent-sweep-start]
2017-03-20T16:23:08.485-0200: 65.588: [CMS-concurrent-sweep: 0.027/0.027 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]
2017-03-20T16:23:08.485-0200: 65.589: [CMS-concurrent-reset-start]
2017-03-20T16:23:08.497-0200: 65.601: [CMS-concurrent-reset: 0.012/0.012 secs] [Times: user=0.01 sys=0.00, real=0.01 secs]
```

How can I confirm the reason for the full gc is to expand metaspace?

Comment: There's no full GC in that log.

Comment: It's [Major GC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592736/2361308) actually.

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8:

**Metaspace capacity**

By default class metadata allocation is limited by the amount of available native memory (capacity will of course depend if you use a 32-bit JVM vs. 64-bit along with OS virtual memory availability).
A new flag is available (MaxMetaspaceSize), allowing you to limit the amount of native memory used for class metadata. If you don’t specify this flag, the Metaspace will dynamically re-size depending of the application demand at runtime.

**Metaspace garbage collection**

**Garbage collection of the dead classes and classloaders is triggered once the class metadata usage reaches the “MaxMetaspaceSize”.**
Proper monitoring & tuning of the Metaspace will obviously be required in order to limit the frequency or delay of such garbage collections. Excessive Metaspace garbage collections may be a symptom of classes, classloaders memory leak or inadequate sizing for your application.

Comment: May i know the reason for the `gc` is the metaspace `getting` full?

Comment: Actually, in the articles I read there were no mention of reasons. If you use   MaxMetaspaceSize option, GC will run when metaspace size you choose is almost reached. If you use default MaxMetaspaceSize - GC will run every time before dynamic expansion metaspace size.